# Print specific element consuming SOAP with XML

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm using the integrated SOAP client in PHP 5.3 and I've tested with this web service: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx

I'm calling this method 'GetWeather' and the XML request looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <CityName>string</CityName>
      <CountryName>string</CountryName>
    </GetWeather>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and response XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetWeatherResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <GetWeatherResult>string</GetWeatherResult>
    </GetWeatherResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So far I'm getting successfully the array with this code:

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL'); 
    $result = $client->GetWeather(array('CityName' => 'Barcelona', 'CountryName' => 'Spain'));
    print_r ($result);
```

How can I print specific element, let's say the value of the CityName?

So when I want to print the city like this:

```
echo '<div> ' . $city . '</div>';
```

How do I get the value of the CityName?